# Wanting to get an output and run a programme together with Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, python-multithreading

What I want to be able to do is run a list of MIDI files, I have the programme to list them out and play them...

```
import os,fnmatch,pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
List = []
Song = 0
def Update():
    List = []
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.mid'):
            List.append(file)
    return List
List = Update()
while True:
    while Song <= len(List):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(List[Song])
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1)
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            List = Update()
        Song = Song + 1
    Song = 0
```

This currently works with .mid files that it is in the same folder as, however I want to implement a slider with the programme to control the volume, I also have that code already...

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()

def getThrottle(event):
    Volume = Throttle.get()

Throttle = Scale(master, from_=0, to=100, tickinterval=10, length=200, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=getThrottle)
Throttle.set(0)
Throttle.pack()

mainloop()
```

What I want to know is how I can make both programmes run at the same time with a single variable global between both with that variable being Volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I discovered how to run both a tkinter window and music at the same time, however a new problem is that the tkinter window is blank.

New question is "[Why is the tkinter window blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976875/why-is-the-tkinter-window-blank)"